# How to use the TCP traceroute in Juniper?

Tags: tcp, juniper, traceroute

How to use the TCP traceroute in Juniper?

In Juniper OS I only know

```
traceroute ip_address
```

I don't know how to traceroute a destination with TCP protocol. is it possible to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tcptraceroute` is a 3rd party binary, so it's not something you can use by default.

> is it possible to implement it?

Yes, but with inherent security risk.

Some platforms have an Enhanced Automation (QFX) image available (see [here](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/concept/junos-flex-overview.html) and [here](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/task/configuration/junos-script-automation-invoking-python.html)).  From the 2nd link:

*The Junos OS with Enhanced Automation software image is a full-featured version of Junos OS that bundles additional automation tools with the image and disables Veriexec enforcement.*

Basically, it lets operators who use automation tools like Puppet or Chef run necessary components on Junos.

You could implement `tcptraceroute` in Python when using this type of image.

The other method is to manually adjust the necessary kernel variables with `sysctl` from a root shell.  I wouldn't recommend this as it would be considered unsupported, so if something happened, JTAC might not be able to help you.